# If there exist any $c, d$ so that $\frac{a_{new}}{b_{new}}\rightarrow \frac{c}{d}$ but never reaches $\frac{c}{d}$, I think

Tags: limits, algorithms, fractions, gcd-and-lcm, continued-fractions

> I have an algorithm to solve this problem  * given two valid simplifying fractions $\dfrac{a}{b}$ and $\dfrac{c}{d},$ each transformation is adding both $a$ and $b$ by $+1,$ simplifying it, again and again until we meet $\dfrac{c}{d}.$ Count the number of steps used, $0$ if none" so that $\dfrac{a}{b}, \dfrac{c}{d}< 1$ and $0< a< b\leq 10^{5}, 0< c< d\leq 10^{5}.$ Easily, I see that the steps only continue if $ad< bc.$ Because we have that $\dfrac{a}{b}< \dfrac{a+ 1}{b+ 1}\overset{\div gcd(a, b)}{\rightarrow}\dfrac{a_{new}}{b_{new}}\rightarrow \dfrac{c}{d}.$ That sounds good.

But my test is not perfect, I wonder if there exist any $c, d$ so that $\dfrac{a_{new}}{b_{new}}\rightarrow \dfrac{c}{d}$ but never reaches $\dfrac{c}{d}.$ I need to your helps.

Comment: No, that's not possible for a,b,c,d e IN

Comment: I can't imagine it. On the other hand, my algorithm is maybe infinite that way, I think I missed one or two conditions.

Comment: @ThomasSablik that's not the equation $\dfrac{a+ x}{b+ x}= \dfrac{c}{d}$ so that you needn't try by computer I still test by it.... but not any onservations.

Comment: No, mathematically it's impossible.

Comment: Notice all elements of the sequence are of the form $(a+x)/(b+x)$ for $x\ge0$.

Comment: @KentaS no, i.e., $\dfrac{1}{6}\rightarrow \dfrac{2}{7}\rightarrow \dfrac{3}{8}\rightarrow \dfrac{4}{9}\rightarrow \dfrac{5}{10}:=\dfrac{1}{2}\rightarrow \dfrac{2}{3}.$

Comment: And $\dfrac{1+ 9}{6+ 9}= \dfrac{2}{3}.$

Comment: Not easy game..

Comment: You just said what I was going to say; $2/3$ is of the desired form. This is enough to answer your question.

Comment: What I meant is the above game, what you meant is the below equation, at all.. thank you.

Comment: $c/d = 1 - e$, for $c, d \in IN$. $\lim_{x -> \infty}\frac{a + x}{b+x} = 1$. That means that there exists one `x` so that $\frac{a}{b} >= \frac{c}{d}$

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence

Comment: okay, $c= 10^{5}- 1, d= 10^{5},$ so what are $a, b$ here ??

Comment: @PM2Ring yes !! You read me like a book

Comment: Do you know what is the limit of that sequence, sir

Comment: There's a *lot* of info about Farey sequences in Allen Hatcher's *Topology of Numbers*, especially in the early chapters. See https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/TN/TNpage.html

Comment: Thanks a rl lot

Comment: I wanna cry sir

Comment: Note that $b-a$ is non-increasing and decreases by division. So as soon as $d-c$ does not divide $b-a$ any more, you know that you cannot succeed

Comment: Roger that, sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find $x$ such that $\frac{a+x}{b+x}=\frac cd$, i.e. $x=\frac{bc-ad}{d-c}$. If this is negative or not an integer, fail immediately.
Otherwise, of all prime divisors $p$ of $b-a$, find the one minimising $y:=p-(b \bmod p)$. If $y\ge x$, the answer is $x$, otherwise it is $y$ plus the result for $\frac{a+y}{b+y}$ (simplified) abd$\frac cd$.

Comment: Thks in advance